# Loading a instance of a class dynamically in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, xib, nib

I would like to init an instance of a class specified at runtime. I have the following set up.

```
//MyClass1 & MyClass2 inherit from UIViewController
let arr = MyClass1.self,MyClass2.self] 

func didSelectRow(index:Int) {
    var controllerRef = arr[index] //This returns a .Type
    var controllerClass = controllerRef() //This returns “the class” MyClass1
    //This is where I'm stuck. How do I initialize controller??

    //Finally, push VC
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
}
```

To initialize the VC with Objective C, I was able to do this as follows:

```
UIViewController *controller = [((UIViewController *)[controllerClass alloc]) initWithNibName:class1Nib bundle:nil];
```

With Swift, I’m expecting something like the syntax below, but it doesn’t work

```
//Doesn’t work
var controller = (controllerClass as UIViewController)(nibName: class1Nib, bundle:nil) 

//Overriding the init method in MyClass1 and then calling the below doesn’t work
var controller = controllerClass(nibName: class1Nib, bundle:nil)

//The below works, but viewDidLoad() does not get called. It only loads the nib file

var controller = UIViewController(nibName: Class1Nib, bundle:nil)
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is this about the nib file or about instantiating the view controller by its class?

Comment: This is not code: `let arr = MyClass1.self,MyClass2.self]` You need to provide _real code_ when you ask a question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: It's about instantiating a view controller. Sorry about that, I've edited the title. It is real code and I don't have to provide real class names and variables - there are innumerable posts with FooBar examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question, with its repeated and meaningless "doesn't work" and "the below", is confused and confusing, so I will respond by assuming that what you want to do is instantiate and push a view controller given its class, and I will simply demonstrate in a few lines of code that this is possible.

Here is a function that returns a UIViewController subclass:

```
func provideVCClass() -> UIViewController.Type {
    return ViewController.self
}
```

And here are lines from a button's action handler where we call that function and use the class to instantiate that view controller and push it onto the current navigation controller:

```
let vcclass = provideVCClass()
let vc = vcclass(nibName: "View", bundle: nil)
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

I assure you that this *does* work: the correct view controller subclass *is* instantiated, its nib *is* loaded, and its view *does* appear in the interface.

So all I can say in answer to your question, which I don't fully understand, is Go Ye And Do Likewise.

**EDIT** Here's a little postscript. If your code actually says:

```
let arr = [MyClass1.self, MyClass2.self]
```

I would suggest you try saying

```
let arr : [UIViewController] = [MyClass1.self, MyClass2.self]
```

...just in case Swift is not inferring the correct type here.

Comment: Your answer worked thanks.  Saying something 'doesn't work' is not meaningless. It means I have tried a few options and spent a few hours.   'The below' in my post refers to the line immediately after. I'm not sure what the fuss is all about!

Comment: @user714223 If you don't like my answer, please don't accept it!